# Apple LLVM 9.0 Error Group-Could not read profile. No such File or Directory Found

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, certificate, sign

I have created distribution certificate and distribution provision profile.
while trying to build application. Its throwing following error.

> Could not read profile
>   /Users/nan/Projects/Projectname/node_modules/react-native/React/OptimizationProfiles/React.profdata:
>   No such file or directory

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out!

1. Go to the Project dropdown and select your **Target**
2. Go to Build Settings
3. Under Apple LLVM 9.0 - code generation, find Use Optimization Profile and select no

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your xCode is up to date

```
Go to Project -> Build Setting -> Apple LLVM 9.2-code generation

and clear Optimization Profile File

Clean Your project.....
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: how to clear Optimization profile.. There is Yes/No. I'm using Xcode 9.2