# React Native Build Error: Could not read optimization profile file (even after change optimization configuration)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, optimization, react-native-ios

I was trying to solve some provision issue with steps in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDN1Dp_GqnM), after that the building process keeps reporting error.

The steps in that video are:

`1. project -> clean
2. project -> build
3. project -> perform action -> Generate Optimization File
4. Enable Optimazation`
 
[image]

It does help me to run the App on connected device. But after this, the building process keeps failing with below error message:

`Could not read profile [My Project Folder]/node_modules/react-native/React/OptimizationProfiles/React.profdata: No such file or directory`

After looking around on SO for hours, I've tried different approaches below but none of them worked:
1)

```
Go to Project -> Build Setting -> Apple LLVM 9.2-code generation  
clear Optimization Profile File // clear is removing the value to empty, correct?  
Clean project and build again
```

optimization level is `none` for all targets:
[image: optimization level is none for all targets]
[source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110213/apple-llvm-9-0-error-group-could-not-read-profile-no-such-file-or-directory-fou)

2. Manually set the path of Optimization Profile File to another location(no profdata file generated btw, it is another error, but it runs app on connected device)
3. Remove `DerivedData` folder as suggested in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480316/archive-apple-llvm-6-0-error-could-not-read-profile)
4. Remove Build folder
5. Clear Xcode Preference and reinstall Xcode

Whenever I build it is still trying to find file in `/node_modules/react-native/React/OptimizationProfiles/React.profdata`. Same result when using `react-native run-ios`. Is it some kind of cache?(although I removed DerivedData Folder, Build Folder, and cleaned project after).Here is more info of the error message:
[image]

```
CompileC `MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGNodeList.o `MyProjectFolder`/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/'ausername'/Documents/dev_fs/RecycleWizard/node_modules/react-native/React
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/`SomeUserName`/anaconda/bin:/Users/'SomeUserName'/Documents/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:./node_modules/.bin:/Users/'SomeUserName'/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/Users/'SomeUserName'/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin:/Users/'SomeUserName'/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/Library/JAVA/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/`SomeUserName`/.rvm/bin:/Users/`SomeUserName`/.rvm/bin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=`MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=`MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wshadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wnewline-eof -DDEBUG=1 -DRCT_DEBUG=1 -DRCT_DEV=1 -DRCT_NSASSERT=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -fprofile-instr-use=`MyProjectFolder`/node_modules/react-native/React/OptimizationProfiles/React.profdata -index-store-path `MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Index/DataStore -I`MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/yoga.hmap -I`MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I`MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I`MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/DerivedSources -Wextra -Wall -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -F`MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF `MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGNodeList.d --serialize-diagnostics `MyProjectFolder`/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGNodeList.dia -c `MyProjectFolder`/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c -o `MyProjectFolder`/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGNodeList.o
```

Any idea of other approaches to try? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution (but it requires some extent of repeated set up work), if you encountered same issue and none of the approaches listed in the question worked, you can try this (as the last resort):

I looked at the log in terminal after `react-native run-ios` failed with following error:

```
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier 
build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SomeProject.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

As suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308#issuecomment-219597774), `react-native upgrade` (react-native version is `0.47.2`), to make sure all the cache is cleaned, I also did this as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14838#issuecomment-313362875):

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -rf yarn.lock
rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn install
```

After these steps, the rest is basically setting up the project again, I did `react native link` and all the other configuration for react native plugin(such as update info.plist). But the project can build successfully after.

I am not sure if it's a bug in Xcode or RN (after I used `perform action -> generate optimization file`) it keeps trying to find that file `/node_modules/react-native/React/OptimizationProfiles/React.profdata` which is weird.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer worked funny thing is the same video mislead me.

Comment: @DanielBarde Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with all the online answers I find is that they tell you to remove the optimisation on project level, with me it need to be done on target level

[image]

So click on your project -> then select your target -> build settings -> Use optimization profile

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar issue. `The only thing i didn't do was run react-native upgrade .` 
Doing this removed the optimization profile error.

Delete the `ios/build` folder

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -rf yarn.lock
rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn install
```